# ionic getting textbox value

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi I'm new to ionic and I have the following html and js code. I am trying to get the value of user input on textbox upon clicking on the button. (If possible, I would like to store it into an object or a local cache so that it could be use throughout the same session)

```
<ion-navbar *navbar hideBackButton>
     <ion-title>Welcome</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>

<ion-list>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Please enter a nickname</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>

<div padding>
    <button (click)="login()" primary block>Continue</button>
</div>
```

next my .js code

```
 import {Component} from "@angular/core";
 import {MenuController, NavController, Alert} from "ionic-angular";
 import {Index} from "../index/index";

 @Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
 })
 export class Login {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[MenuController], [NavController]];
    }

 constructor(menu, nav) {
        this.menu = menu;
        this.menu.swipeEnable(false);

        this.nav = nav;
    }

    login() {
        let alert = Alert.create({
        title:      'You have entered',
        message:    'Hello',
        buttons:    [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Ok clicked');

                    console.log(getElementById('nickname'));

                    // this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
                    // this.nav.pop(Login);
                    // this.nav.setRoot(Index);
      }
    }
  ]
    });

    this.nav.present(alert);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic works with angular which has two way binding as its core principal. There are lots of way to accomplish this but one way is to set a model of an html item.
So if you set your input to have an ng model

```
<ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="inputName"></ion-input>
```

and then in your controller(class) you'll have

```
this.inputName;
```

It will hold the value changes from html.

Comment: thanks it worked! may I know why must my ngmodel be in an object?

Comment: Its not an object in this example. Do you mean why its supposed to be in the controller as a property? If you want you can read about this in angular 1 https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: thanks! just one more qns! is it possible to get the same name over at the next page?

Comment: Not with an ng model since every page has its own SCOPE of data. But if you really want to you can pass your data using your NavController like this.nav.push(SecondView, { paramUser: user }); (don't forget to set routing of the navcontroller to make it possible) Read up for more: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/

Comment: How  to  get  value,if ion-input is  created  dynamically  using *ngFor

Comment: Same idea, but let the model be part of the collection in ngfor

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about ionic2 but in ionic 1 we can do like below:

Here is an example to store the value of use input text into and object

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username">
<input type="text" ng-model="password">
<button class="button"ng-click="login(username,password)"> submit</button>
```

in your js file

```
$scope.login= function(username,password){
   console.log(username);
   console.log(password);
var loginUser = {
     "username":username,
     "password":password
};
console.log(loginUser);
```

check this answer it always work for me.

Comment: Hi I have tried this however It's not working for my case. Do I need to initialize angular?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<input type="text" name="input name" ng-model="variable-to-bind" />
```

You can access `variable-to-bind` from controller using `$scope` .

***For example:***.

- In your case `variable-to-bind` is `username`, you can access it like `$scope.username`